# How do you get the sceptre in spelunky html5

Tags: spelunky-html5

I would like to know how to get the scepter in Spelunky HTML 5.

Comment: Have you tried using a guide? If the guide fails, then would be a good time to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Spelunky HTML5 is ported directly from the original Game Maker version, so the methods are exactly the same as in the original game. You get the sceptre by killing the mummy on floor 13 and picking it up.

http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/Scepter (click the tab for Spelunky classic)

Comment: Although please do yourself a favour and download the game instead of playing in HTML5. The HTML5 performance is terribly laggy, and the original downloadable version is 100% free (legally!) from here http://www.spelunkyworld.com/original.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sceptre by killing the mummy at level 13 - level 16. 
 To kill the mummy, it is best to use the shotgun to kill it. The mummy spawns flies out of its mouth, decreasing 2 health when contacted. Or, you could throw a bomb if you don't have weapons, and time it at the exact moment where it is.
 The best way to do it without wasting anything is to jump on the mummy, usually done on platforms above the mummy. You can jump on the mummy for several times until it dies, but if you are not controlling well you could easily be killed.